# Giving error when retrieving data from Firebase with Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i included these cdn in my html:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-database.js"></script> 

<script src="StoreFeatured.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and here is the store featured code

```
var firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "$$$$$$$",
authDomain: "$$$$$$",
databaseURL: "https://thegreatpcstore.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "thegreatpcstore",
storageBucket: "thegreatpcstore.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "302435893791",
appId: "$$$$$$$",
measurementId: "G-0GH3F41E5S"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

new function GetData() 
{
    firebase.database().ref('/Products/Motherboard/1').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {

            //var Description = snapshot.val().Description;
            var Name = snapshot.val().Name;
            var Price = snapshot.val().Price;
            var ImageStr = snapshot.val().ImageStr;

            document.getElementById("Mi"+i).src=ImageStr;
            document.getElementById("Mn"+i).innerHTML=Name;
            document.getElementById("Mp"+i).innerHTML=Price;
        }     
    )
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

im getting these errors:

```
> firebase-auth.js:206 Uncaught Error: Cannot find the firebase namespace; be sure to include firebase-app.js before this library.
    at firebase-auth.js:206
    at firebase-auth.js:206
    at firebase-auth.js:206
> 
> firebase-database.js:38 Uncaught Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Failed
> to register the Firebase Database Service (TypeError:
> firebase.INTERNAL.registerService is not a function) 
>     at dd (firebase-database.js:38)
>     at firebase-database.js:245
>     at firebase-database.js:245
> 
> StoreFeatured.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: firebase.database is not a
> function
>     at new GetData (StoreFeatured.js:17)
>     at StoreFeatured.js:13
```

first line of getdata() is doing problem i think im doing something wrong with cdn... please help

if i remove the cdn it gives one error:

```
StoreFeatured.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: firebase.database is not a function
at new GetData (StoreFeatured.js:16)
at StoreFeatured.js:13
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the same version in all firebase dependencies ? I see `7.6.1` and `3.1.0`.

Comment: i copied it from an answer did not looked at it :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update both the firebase-auth and firebase-database to the following version:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks you so much did not realized it was that simple!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using various CDN use a single CDN which include all the library:

```
script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.4/firebase.js"
```